# How to update an ancestral element class in response to child input change with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue (v2.6.11) and I want to add/remove a class on an ancestor (grandparent) element of an input (checkbox) when it's value is changed. There are an unknown number of checkboxes so they are generated using `v-for` on the element that I want to add/remove the class. I have a function registered with my Vue instance `methods` when the checkbox value is changed.

In my code below, the `<label>` is the element to which I want to add/remove the class in response to the checkbox value changing. I'm trying to resist the urge to apply an `:id` attribute to the label and then do a lookup in my `updateCounter` method that will use the `id` of the checkbox to find the label and add/remove the class using pure JS. Is there a more Vue-esque way to do this?

```
<label class="item"     
    v-for="item in myItems"
    v-bind:key="item.id"
    :for="'item'+item.id">

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox"
            :id="'item'+item.id"
            v-model="item.isAccepted" 
            @change="updateCounter($event)" />

        <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
        <span>{{ item.status }}</span>
    </div>

    <div>{{ item.date }}</div>

</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a dynamic class like so: `:class="item.applyClass ? 'item' : ' ' "` so put a property on the item and then you can dynamically change that in your `updatedCounter` function

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
<label class="item"     
v-for="item in myItems"
v-bind:key="item.id"
:for="'item'+item.id"
:class="{test: item.isAccepted === true}">

<div>
    <input type="checkbox"
        :id="'item'+item.id"
        v-model="item.isAccepted" 
        @change="updateCounter($event)" />

    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span>{{ item.status }}</span>
</div>

<div>{{ item.date }}</div>
```

This would apply test class only when is Accepted is true for that particular checkbox.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that `isAccepted` is not really the condition I want for adding/removing the class. When my data is initially loaded, there might be lots of checkboxes that already have `isAccepted` set to true, but I only want the class applied when the user has changed the value of the checkbox. I will use the `:class` directive though, I'll just use a new property on item.

Comment: Even in that case, I should've done :class="{test: item.isAccepted === true}" rather than making use of index. I'll updated this.